# Why doesn't pin code/pattern work?

Tags: lock-screens

I have a Samsung Galaxy Grand Prime and when I set a pin code it would show up, but it would switch back to swipe to unlock even though I have it secured as PIN. It just occasionally switches my screen lock to swipe and to PIN and I can't figure out how to make it stay as PIN.

Comment: Did you mind resetting it? Backing up all your data first of course.

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider trying other screen lock screen apps from playstore?(If not please do!)

If this doesn't work then a factory reset might do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Go to apps in settings then list of apps all check your permission on each app one of them has,ability to change lock security's then disable that permission  hope it helps